# DRY struct tags in Go

Tags: xml-parsing, go, dry

I'm parsing XML, and at most every level of the document, there's a `description`.

Here's an toy example:

```
<obj>
    <description>outer object</description>
    <subobjA>
        <description>first kind of subobject</description>
        <foo>some goop</foo>
    </subobjA>
    <subobjB>
        <description>second kind of subobject</description>
        <bar>some other goop</bar>
    </subobjB>
</obj>
```

This means that every struct involved has an identical `Description` member, with an identical tag `` `xml:"description,omitempty"` ``.

Here's functioning code: http://play.golang.org/p/1-co6Qcm8d

I'd rather the Description tags be DRY. The obvious thing to want to do is something like:

```
type Description string `xml:"description,omitempty"`
```

and then use the type `Description` throughout. However, only struct members can have tags. See http://play.golang.org/p/p83UrhrN4u for what I want to write; it doesn't compile.

One could create a `Description` struct and embed it repeatedly, but that adds a layer of indirection when accessing.

Is there another way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedding a re-factored `Description` struct (as you already suggested) is the way to go:

[(Playground)](http://play.golang.org/p/lmvyGP8pwk)

```
type describable struct{
    Description string `xml:"description"`
}

type subobjA struct {
    describable
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"subobjA"`
}

type subobjB struct {
    describable
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"subobjB"`
}

type obj struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"obj"`
    A           subobjA
    B           subobjB
}
```

The mentioned layer of indirection does not exist. To cite [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) on that topic:

> A field or method f of an anonymous field in a struct x is called promoted if x.f is a legal selector that denotes that field or method f.
>
> Promoted fields act like ordinary fields of a struct except that they cannot be used as field names in composite literals of the struct.

So you can do this:

```
err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(sampleXml), &sampleObj)
fmt.Println(sampleObj.Description)
fmt.Println(sampleObj.A.Description)
```

`sampleObj.describable.Description` is promoted to be `sampleObj.Description`, so no further layer of indirection here.

Comment: Ahhh...when I tried this, I foolishly called my embedded struct `Description` (instead of `descriptable`). Thanks!

Comment: 'type describable', surely? (descriptable is not a real word is it?)

Comment: @Rick-777 yeah, sorry. fixed that